# NSObject instead of the header file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I made an simple UITableViewCell. I put there image view and an label.

I'm trying to drag them to the header file and then use them.

But once I'm clicking on the tuxedo icon I'm getting an NSObject.h instead of WorkoutCell.h .

[Here is a picture](http://gyazo.com/8c93dc38438d40ee684d55950961de7f.png):

[image: Description]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/8c93dc38438d40ee684d55950961de7f.png))</sub>

I'm trying to add the label and the image view. but I'm pretty new to ios/iphone/xcode so if there is any other way to do it without dragging it (with the ctrl key ofc) to the header file. please let me know .. ;)

and yes I tried to navigate to that header file, but it doesn't appear there ..

Comment: Please add the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your cell's class in the identity inspector is **NSObject** . Change it to **WorkoutCell.h** . Now try

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen lots of times before.

If you click the third icon from the left of the tuxedo, you can navigate your project files.
From here select the folder your WorkOutCell.h is in.

Maybe someone else can provide a more comprehensive answer as to why this happens, but with this navigation you will at least be able to access your WorkOutCell.h

Answer (score 0):

In your Interface Builder you need to set the custom class of the view.

1) Click on the view in interface builder.
2) On the right pan choose the 3rd tab from the left.
3) Choose the right Custom Class.